# Append Iframe SRC attribute parameter with value of a cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, url-parameters

Thanks ahead for your guidance, help and expertise community!

A user comes to my site with a campaign parameter in the URL, and we are 'storing that value as a cookie'.

Wondering if I can use JS or JQ and attach that cookie value to src string for embedded iframes.

EX:

```
<iframe src="www.mysite.com/thisform?campaign="the-cookie-value">
```

Basically, I want to pass the cookie as a URL parameter within Iframes SRC.
These iframes will all reference the same domain - in this example 'mysite.com'

Comment: Yes you can, but the cookie is not needed.  You can take it from the Url and pass it to the iframe src attribute without a cookie.  Please read **[ask]** and then update your question with any existing relevant code so we can help.

Comment: Thanks Archer! I will read up on the How to Ask.
My challenge with pulling from url string - the campaign cookie is kept by the browser. Users who close the browser and come back may submit a form. Therefore, I would like to utilize the cookie. Do you think this is possible? I'm totally a newb to all of this.

Comment: Yes, you can access your own cookies and use the data in them.

Comment: Archer - I've added the code. I would like to find a method to pull a specific cookie value and append it as a query parameter to a SRC string on an iframe. I've searched all over and I cannot find an example of this. Any push in the right direction would be super helpful! Appreciate your time and knowledge.

Comment: look at the example #2 : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie
or : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#Security where the snippets is doing almost exactly what you want

Comment: Thanks @jonatjano! That's a start. Now I just need to learn more JS and actually figure out how to:
1) Find out the an existing paramter value in an Iframe Source
2) Apply the cookie value/replace
Unfortunately I'm not that smart yet! haha Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to get the value of your cookie :

```
let cookieValue = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)your-cookie-name\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
// replace your-cookie-name as needed
```

then you get your iframe :

```
let iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
// change the 0 if your iframe is not the first of the page
// ordered by apparence in HTML file
```

finally set the source :

```
iframe.src = "http://www.example.com/thisform?campaign=" + cookieValue;
//change this ^^^^ to https if needed
```

sometime the target doesn't allow accessing them by iframe (example: you can't open http://google.com in an iframe) so make sure your server doesn't block you.